# Run PHP query to check if DB has been updated. Async? Continuously? Other approaches?

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous

I have a forum that is populated according to the contents of a database in MySQL.

What I want to do is to check the DB and see if any other user has replied to my post. I tried to run a PHP script continuously, but it slow downs my server and we are not permitted to run the script for more than a minute

Are there any alternatives where I can run this code to check for new replies? Pretty much I want to check and see if the DB has been updated without having to reload the page and without having the user click a button.

Comment: Yes, just have a socket connection dispatching when a post has been made. You can use NodeJS + socket.io and make the link between the two via PHP sessions via Redis for example.

Comment: You can also use PHP for the socket server if you aren't comfortable learning NodeJS. I have created quite a few applications using Ratchet http://socketo.me/

Comment: There's no need for a complicated async/node/etc/ solution.  I would simply use Javascript to ping an API that returns true/false if a thread has replies, or replies after a certain date, etc.